# Vim: wrap text ("gq") without modifying underlined headings

Tags: formatting, markdown, text-formatting, vim

Is there a way of formatting text in Vim that respects underlined headings?

In Markdown, there are two ways of representing headings:

```
#Level 1 heading
##Level 2 heading
###Level 3 heading
```

and for level 1 & 2 only:

```
Level 1 heading
===============

Level 2 heading
---------------
```

I am fond of the underlining style, as I think it reads better.

When I compose markdown in Vim with, say, `:set textwidth=72`, I would like to be able to reformat the entire document with `gggqG`, but it treats these underlined headings as paragraphs, and squeezes them together onto one line. So if I started with the following:

```
Lorem ipsum
===========

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

After running `gq` on the entire passage, I would end up with something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum ===========

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat.
```

Is there any way that I can prevent Vim from formatting the underlined headings?

I suppose there must be a solution using either [`formatexpr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'formatexpr') or [`formatprg`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'formatprg'). I have studied the documentation for [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/), and despite being very powerful it looks as though this is not one of its features. So I'm wondering if there is another external program which could be used with `formatprg` that understands markdown, or if this can be achieved instead using vimscript with the `formatexpr` setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option that *sorta* works is to add the underline strings to the `comments` variable.

If your underline strings are a fixed size, you could add just those:

```
:set comments+=:---------------,:===============
```

If they're variable size (more than one):

```
:set comments+=n:--,n:==
```

Using more-than-one allows a paragraph to start with a single `-` or `=` and keeps subsequent lines from being prepended with the comment string.

Remove the `+` above to set comments just to those strings instead of adding them on.

There are some cases where the formatting will act unexpectedly (e.g. underlines on consecutive lines).  I'm sure there's a more appropriate way to do this but hopefully this will get you started.

```
:h comments
:h format-comments
:h formatoptions
:h fo-table
```

Comment: This feels kind of hackish, but as long as the `q` flag is included in the `formatoptions` setting it works fine. My underline strings usually match the length of the text on the line above, so I used the variable size setting. Thanks for helping out.

In addition to the help references listed in the answer, I found this to be helpful: [`:help 30.6`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_30.html#30.6)

Answer (score 0):

At least you can set up some macro for it.

E.g. postion the text somehow on the first paragraph with searching for the first headline-underline then move down 2 lines, then visuallí select the area to the next underline minus 3 line, then format it:

```
qa/^===========$/jjv/^===========$/-3<CR>gqq
```

Now you can use your `a` macro.

HTH